How is classical Chern-Simons theory topological?
Note: I am using "global" and "topological" somewhat interchangable. This seems to be the case in texts and papers, but please point out if this is inappropriate.
Classical Chern-Simons theory takes place on the following data: a principal bundle $(P, M, \pi, G)$ with (dynamically determined) connection $1$-form $\omega$ and Chern-Simons action $S$. We fix $\dim M = 3$ and assume $M$ is oriented and closed. We call the pullback of $\omega$ via loacl sections a gauge potential and denote it by $A$. We say that $A$ is on-shell if it satisfies the equation of motion induced by the principle of stationary action.
Introductions to Chern-Simons theory then proceed to make various simplifications.
Non-abelian theory
In particular, in Freed's notes, part 1 he

Assumes that $G$ is compact, connected, and simply-connected. Immediately, this means that $G$ cannot be abelian since there does not exist an abelian Lie group satisfying the aforementioned restrictions.
States the theorem that $(P, M, \pi, G)$ with $G$ simply-connected and $\dim M = 3$ must be a trivial bundle.

Hence, in this simplification of Chern-Simons theory, we are working over a trivial bundle with a non-abelian, compact, connected, and simply-connected structure group. The triviality of the bundle ensures that the often writ form of the Chern-Simons action
$$S \propto \int_M \kappa (A \wedge dA + \frac{2}{3}A\wedge A\wedge A) \tag{1}$$
where $\kappa$ is the Killing form on $\text{Lie}(G) = \mathfrak{g}$ is well-defined. Stationizing this action leads to the equation of motion
$$F = dA + A \wedge A = 0. \tag{2}$$
Gauge transformations are given by
$$A \to D_X A = A + dX + A \wedge X.$$
Abelian theory
Now, let us assume that $G$ is abelian. Let us also naively assume that the equation of motion is still
$$F = dA = 0$$
where the second term in $(2)$ vanishes due to $G$ being abelian. Gauge transformations are given by
$$A \to D_X A = A + dX.$$
Hence, the gauge equivalence class of on-shell gauge potentials is the first de Rham cohomology class $H^1(M)$. A sequence of identifications leads to the fact that
$$H^1(M) \cong \text{Hom}(H_1(M, \mathbb{Z}), \mathbb{R})$$
where $H_1(M, \mathbb{Z})$ is the abelianization of the fundamental group $\pi_1(M)$. In this sense, we can directly see that abelian Chern-Simons theory depends on a topological property of the base manifold.
The question
To my understanding, the whole point of Chern-Simons theory or even the bundle formalism of field theory is to keep track of the global properties of the bundle over which the theory takes place. This is at least conceivable in the abelian theory where the state space is $H^1(M)$ which is intimately connected with $\pi_1(M)$, a topological quantity of the base manifold. My questions are:

In the simplified non-abelian Chern-Simons theory described, what global properties of the bundle are even left to detect?
How does the simplified non-abelian Chern-Simons theory described detect these global properties of the bundle?

